# PrimeNG Nested P-panel using PrimeNG Grid

Tags: angular, mean-stack, primeng

I am trying to achieve 4 small panels inside of a parent panel

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
      <p-panel header="Statistics">
        <div class="ui-g-6">
          <p-panel header="Clients">
            Total clients: {{clients.length}}
          </p-panel>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-6">
          <p-panel header="Products">
            Total products: <!--TODO-->
          </p-panel>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-6">
          <p-panel header="Orders">
            Total orders: <!--TODO-->
          </p-panel>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-6">
          <p-panel header="Vendor Orders">
            Total vendor orders: <!--TODO-->
          </p-panel>
        </div>
      </p-panel>
    </div>
```

However, the result is not what I wanted:
[image]

I got rid of all the ui-g-6 and got:
[image]

Any advise on how to achieve the first layout but inside the parent panel like in the 2nd picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, wrap your inner panels inside a new grid (you've created a new container with the panel, so you need a new grid).

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
    <p-panel header="Statistics">
        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p-panel header="Clients">
                    Total clients: {{clients.length}}
                </p-panel>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p-panel header="Products">
                    Total products:
                    <!--TODO-->
                </p-panel>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p-panel header="Orders">
                    Total orders:
                    <!--TODO-->
                </p-panel>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p-panel header="Vendor Orders">
                    Total vendor orders:
                    <!--TODO-->
                </p-panel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-panel>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Somehow I thought of doing this when I first encountered the issue but totally ignored it. Marked as answer.